# PHP Wordpress Simple Redirect by Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I need to check if the user is logged in, and depending on the result, I want the user to be redirected to custom field A or B. This is my code so far:

```
<?php

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php');

    add_action('get_header', 'redirect');

    function redirect () {
        global $post;
        if (is_page() || is_object($post)) {
            if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect', true)) {
                header('Location: ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect', true));
            }
        }
    }

    function redirect_b () {
        global $post;
        if (is_page() || is_object($post)) {
            if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Shortlink', true)) {
                header('Location: ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Shortlink', true));
            }
        }
    }

    if ($current_user->ID == '') { 
        redirect();
}
else { 

    redirect_b();
}

?>
```

It doesn't work and I get error 500 whenever I activate this. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add `exit;` right after the `header` call, and don't render anything before calling the redirect.

Comment: The answers below are good, but for your reference this code will never evaluate to true. If the current user is not logged in then current user id is 0

    if ($current_user->ID == '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best practice to use `wp_safe_redirect()` to avoid an open redirect.  In this scenario it's not essential to use it as it's not coming from user input but I like to always use this function.  Not that `wp_safe_redirect()` does not exit automatically so should always be followed by an exit call.

```
function redirect_site_user() {

    global $post;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Shortlink', true) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Shortlink', true) );
        }


    } else {
        if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect', true) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect', true) );
        }
    }

    exit;
}

add_action( 'init', 'redirect_site_user' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me! This is not really working though, it's not redirecting to the URL on the custom field

Comment: Check if the get_post_meta functions are returning any data.

Comment: It looks like it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `get_currentuserinfo()` since it's deprecated. You should use `wp_get_current_user()` instead. But in your example, we don't even need it since `is_user_logged_in()` will already use that function to make sure global is set and if not will set it.

The action hook `get_header` is really not the hook you want here because that hook allows a specific header template file to be used in place of the default header template file.

Then if you want to redirect, Wordpress offers a function that does that `wp_redirect()`. So no need to use `header( Location: )`.

Plus, do you really need that condition that checks if it is a page?.

You could try something like this :

```
add_action( 'init', 'control_access' );
function control_access() {

    global $post;


    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

        if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect', true) ) {

            wp_redirect( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect', true) );
            exit;

        }


    } else {

        if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Shortlink', true) ) {

            wp_redirect( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Shortlink', true) );
            exit;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me! This is not really working though, it's not redirecting to the URL on the custom field.